# Avoid duplicates when importing data from json

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm importing data from a json string into a mysql database using a symfony2 command every 15 minutes, but I'm struggling with duplicate entries.

Sample json:

> "a":"Armin van Buuren",
>   "t":"Shivers",

To determine whether it exists i'm using doctrines findByName method:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Entity')->findByName($obj[$i]['t']);
```

followed by two checks

`if(count($entity)==0) {return false;}`

```
if(strcasecmp($entity[0]->getArtist()->getName(), $artist) != 0) {return false;}
```

I don't know why but i'm getting a lot of entries like this:

```
id      artist_id   name                   created_at
3577    30          Satellite              2015-04-12 15:45:04
3578    129         Suburban Train         2015-04-12 15:45:04
3579    317         Traffic                2015-04-12 15:45:04
3575    1062        Holding On To Nothing  2015-04-12 15:45:03
3576    506         Rapture                2015-04-12 15:45:03
3573    129         Suburban Train         2015-04-12 15:30:04
3574    317         Traffic                2015-04-12 15:30:04
3572    30          Satellite              2015-04-12 15:30:03
3571    317         Traffic                2015-04-12 15:15:01
```

Some tracks are getting duplicated but not all.

I've checked the generated sql from doctrine and it looks fine, e.g.:

```
SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.image AS image3, t0.created_at AS created_at4, t0.updated_at AS updated_at5, t0.video_id AS video_id6, t0.artist_id AS artist_id7 FROM Track t0 WHERE t0.name = 'Traffic'
```

What can i do to avoid these duplicates?

**EDIT**

Whole function:

```
private function fetchAction($url) {
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);

    $count = count($obj);
    for($i=0;$i < $count; $i++) {

        $track = $obj[$i]['t'];
        $artist = $obj[$i]['a'];

        if($track==='Unknown Track') continue;
        if($artist==='Unknown Artist') continue;

        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $trackEntity = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Track')->findByName($track);
        $artistEntity = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Artist')->findByName($artist);

        /**
         * check whether artist exists
         */
        if(!$this->artistExists($artistEntity)) {
            $this->createArtist($artist, $em);
        }

        /*
         * check whether track already exists
         */
        if(!$this->trackExists($trackEntity, $artist)) {
            $this->createTrack($obj[$i], $em, $artistEntity);
        }
    }
}

private function trackExists($trackEntity, $artist) {
    if(count($trackEntity)==0) {
        return false;
    }

    if(strcasecmp($trackEntity[0]->getArtist()->getName(), $artist) != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private function artistExists($artistEntity) {
    if(count($artistEntity)==0) return false;
    return true;
}

private function createArtist($artist, $em) {
    $entity = new Artist();
    $entity->setName($artist);
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush($entity);
}

private function createTrack($trackArray, $em, $artistEntity) {
    $entity = new Track();
    $entity->setName($trackArray['t']);
    $entity->setArtist($artistEntity[0]);
    $entity->setImage($this->saveImage($trackArray));
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush($entity);
}
```

Comment: Can we have your whole json treatment ? I think your a using findByName for entries which are not persisted yet.

Comment: Create an unique index on name.  That will not only prevent duplicates but speed your queries up a bit.  And catching the duplicate exception might help discover the source of the problem.

Comment: Post whole code of your function and code where you do `persist()`. Maybe you just messed up with boolean types and naming? E.g. you name your function as `isAlreadyExist()` but your function return false if it is already exist.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the whole function @Cerad you mean make the name column unique? But there are a lot of tracks from different artists with the same name

Comment: Then make track,name unique.  Or whatever set of columns that you want to be unique.